# Should I use the genitive case in Paola's answer?

Tags: possessives

Which of the following sentences is correct?

1. I should've waited until Paola's answer
2. I should've waited until the Paola answer

Should I use the genitive case?

Comment: What's a Paola? What are you waiting for? :)

Comment: If Paola is a person, it should be "Paola's answer".

Comment: I was waiting for her response to my mail..

Comment: Making it according to the past tense: *I should've waited until Paola answered.*

Comment: Although it's perfectly grammatical, in your exact context the second version would be *very* unusual phrasing. In other contexts, such as [*(Let's wait until we've received) **the American response***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22the+American+response%22) it would be perfectly natural (and perhaps even more common than *America's response*).

Comment: ...in fact, [here's proof](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the+American+response+was%2CAmerica%27s+response+was&year_start=1920&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthe%20American%20response%20was%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CAmerica%20%27s%20response%20was%3B%2Cc0) that ***the American response was*** occurs more often in written texts than ***America's response was***.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most natural way to express the idea is to say:

*I should have waited for Paola's answer/response.*

So, yes, in that sense you would be using the "genitive case." Except that modern English does not have a case system. Only textbooks that try to teach English using terminology from Latin will generally refer to cases. Sometimes this is referred to as the "Saxon Genitive,"  but this is based on a case system that existed in English about 1000 years ago.

Most people would just refer to this construction (*Paola's answer/response*) as a "possessive construction."

You could also say

*I should have waited for Paola to answer/respond.*

One could also say

*I should have waited until Paola answered/responded.*

There are probably a dozen other ways to phrase this kind of sentence.

Your version

*I should've waited until Paola's answer*

sounds incomplete, as if there should be a second clause immediately, as in

*I should've waited until Paola's answer before I gave mine.*